# how do i show results of two functions in another function

Tags: function, lambda, set, scheme, racket

I have been as a part of a school assignment been coding a program on racket,which is similar to the tfl route planner. My objective is to create a function which takes the results from the two functions, so I can begin the second phase which is to set a distance of 5 mins between each letter, for example, from a to b is 5 min and a to c is 10 min. I have been searching this on google and stack overflow, but they don't help. here is my code so far.

```
(define line1 (set "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"))

(define line2 (set "f" "g" "c" "h" "i"))

(define line3 (set "k" "i" "l" "m" "e"))

(printf "enter your current posistion")
(define exsists1 (λ (a)
  (cond
    ((empty? a) (error " you need to enter a starting location"))
    ((not (or (set-member? line1 a) (set-member? line2 a) (set-member? line3 a))) 
     (error "enter a location which exisits"))
    (else "enter your final destintation"))))

(define exsists2 (λ (b)
  (cond
    ((empty? b) (error " you need to enter a finishing location"))
    ((not (or (set-member? line1 b) (set-member? line2 b) (set-member? line3 b))) 
     (error "enter a location which exisits"))
    (else "plan your journey"))))
```

Comment: What do you want to compare? The functions don't return anything useful to compare, they just return messages that could be displayed to the user.

Comment: I mean I want the function to display the results from the 2 functions e,g for the first function I choose a and the second b.I want the function to display these results in a form such “your journey between a and b is 5 mins”

Comment: Then just do something like `(write (exsists1 input))` where `input` is the variable you assign the user's input to.

Comment: Forget about all kinds of user interaction at the moment and just write functions that manipulate your data and solve the problem. (Also, your functions are identical except for the `else` result. This situation is usually a hint that you're on the wrong track.)

Comment: Why does the question title say "compare" if you just want to print it?

Comment: Thanks how will implement that into a function

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you are given a list of named “locations” (_a_, _b_, ...) and must compute the distance between two of them (which you will turn into time taken to travel between them)?

Comment: Yes but the locations can vary depending on the user input it can be from c to k.but there is a fixed distance of 5 min between each letter

Answer (score 0):

You are being asked to:

- locate an item in a list
- locate another item in the same list
- find the distance between the two items
- multiply that distance by 5

You should focus, then, on creating a function that returns the index of a value in a list, or `-1` or (size of list) or something invalid if the item does not exist in the list.

```
(define (find x xs)
```

You can then use it:

```
; get line1
; get start
; get stop
(display (* 5 (abs (- (find start line1) (find stop line1)))))
```

Again, don’t worry about invalid inputs *unless your homework especially asks for it*.